# Why use access modifiers

Tags: c#, security, access-modifiers

I know the difference between the different access modifiers and when to use them, but I'm left with the why. I understand that it simplifies a project, but is there any other use e.g. security?

Comment: Access modifiers are a high level concept. It doesn't make your code any more secure. It's all about making it harder to make mistakes, and more straight-forward to code things correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If everything was public it would make maintainability much harder because you would never know for sure whether a class/member could be modified/removed because anything external could be making use of it. If something is declared private/protected/internal, when you return to the code later to make changes you have a clear picture of what can access it and how you can modify without breaking other components.

It also reduces complexity to outside eyes (encapsulation), by hiding internal members.

Answer (score 0):

As a name suggest they allows you to provide access. you can define a class member protected or private which makes them inaccessible for outside the class objects. thus they are more about access rights than security. You can read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

Everything became much clearer in big team. Say, you gave someone your .dll and they don't have your source code. Would you like to write a lot of XML-comments with "USE IT SPARELY".

And sometimes - your .dll is your final product. You need to avoid mistakes

So, use cases which I see fitable:

To avoid usage of internal methods, which shouldn't be called independently. If you have sequence of private methods, - that are using shared properties/fields - you don't want someone to use them and raise unexpected exceptions, right?

To avoid mess with properties/fields, which used for internal purposes

and more...